# CodeIgniter create new custom exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I'm trying to create a custom exception to return a correct message based on `$_FILES[..]['error']` codes.

I have extended the `CI_Exceptions class`:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
    function My_Exceptions() {
        parent::CI_Exceptions();
    }

    public function file_upload_error($error_code = UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        switch ($error_code) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $message = "No file was uploaded";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $message = "Missing a temporary folder";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $message = "Failed to write file to disk";
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $message = "File upload stopped by extension";
                break;

            default:
                $message = "Unknown upload error";
                break;
        }

        log_message('error', $error_code);
        return $message;
    }    
}
```

But when I call `file_upload_error(1)` it says `Call to undefined function file_upload_error()`

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Your function is defined outside your class?

Comment: Show us where and how you call this class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the feeling that you're not using your library class correctly, but it's hard to tell from your question. From a model or controller class, you would use:

```
$this->load->library('exceptions');
$message = $this->exceptions->file_upload_error($error_code);
```

when you tell it to load the exceptions library, it automatically looks to see if there's one in your application/libraries/ directory with the MY_ prefix. If it's there, it will load it. Then you access it as with any other library.

Hope that helps.